# What ports does Exchange MAPI use

Tags: exchange-2010

What ports does Exchange MAPI/CDO use to connect to the Client Access Server from the Mailbox Server. I have a piece of software installed on a Mailbox server that uses Exchange MAPI ([RDO](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo/default.htm) to be specific, which uses Exchange MAPI). The problem is I'm running into MAPI_E_NETWORK_ERROR problems so I was wondering if there might be firewall issues i.e. the Client Access Server (CAS) cannot be accessed properly from the Mailbox server by MAPI. what ports do I need to check in the firewall configuration? This is on Exchange 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAPI actually uses RPC which uses a dynamically assigned port number. Here's a blog posting that will help you make that port number static:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/configuring-static-rpc-ports-on-an-exchange-2010-client-access-server.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check whether your Client Access servers are requiring encryption (use Get-RPCClientAccess to see).  I've encountered problems with third party apps that don't support RPC encryption when the CAS are enforcing it.

Comment: Thanks, already checked that. As far as I know this encryption settings is now actually on by default in 2010 whereas is was off by default in previous versions.